# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load component Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to implement login functionality using angular2-seed project as the base and referring to angular2-login-seed. But I get the following error.
I had a look through the other questions asked relates to the same error but could not figure out what is wrong with my code. Please help.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'
```

My App component code:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  viewProviders: [NameListService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent, ToolbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
     console.log('Environment config', Config);
  }
}
```

app.component.html code:

```
<sd-navbar><router-outlet></router-outlet></sd-navbar>
```

App route config:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [UnauthenticatedGuard]
  },
  ...HomeRoutes,
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
   provideRouter(routes),UnauthenticatedGuard, HomeComponentGuard
];
```

HomeRoutes code:

```
export const HomeRoutes = [
{
   path: '',
   component: HomeComponent,
   canActivate: [HomeComponentGuard],
   children: [
     { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
     { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
     { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
   ]
 },
 ];
```

Home.Component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { NameListService } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'wrapper',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent {
   newName: string;
   constructor(public nameListService: NameListService) {
      console.log("nameList: " + JSON.stringify(nameListService.get()));
   }

   addName(): boolean {
     this.nameListService.add(this.newName);
     this.newName = '';
     return false;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this is not quite the answer that you expected, the problem that we both have ([Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LocalizationListComponent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943629/cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load-localizationlistcomponent?noredirect=1#comment65244017_38943629)) is that this is an intentional behavior.

Every parent must have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Here is a response on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10686.

I spent two entire days trying to figure this thing out. I guess removing `children` or `loadChildren` and treating everything at the same level is one of the ways to go.

This is a very confusing and undocumented feature of the router.

Answer (score 1):

To load your templates do not use

```
templateUrl: 'app.html'
```

on the Component decorator. Instead import your template and reference it as follows

```
import template from './app.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template
})
```